# Android API 21 src folder empty on creation

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have upgraded to API 21 in for Android but when attempting to create a project and selecting the navigation, the resultant project src file is empty:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I have tried to update/patch the ADT using the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download but have had no such luck.

How can this be alleviated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and VicJordan helped me here [Android API 21 only allows creation of empty activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465668/android-api-21-only-allows-creation-of-empty-activity?noredirect=1#comment43367769_27465668)
After upgrading, the ADT and SDK Tools are no longer compatible and there is no version for ADT that is compatible with SDK 24.0.1, I roolbacked to SDK Tools 23.0.5 and is working again.
Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, I have ADT 23.0.4.1468518 and SDK 24.01, How did you roll back? Can we enter a chat?

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work, but my problem persists due to deprecation, another issue