# Android API 21 only allows creation of empty activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

After upgrading to API 21 i can't create new blank activitys in any project and when i create a new one the only activity that allows me to create is an empty one, otherwise it creates the src and res folders empty.
I'm using eclipse. i've tried the solution here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download, but it is already installed.

Please, help.

Comment: All you have to do it create a class that extends Activity

Comment: I know, but it's extra work that eclipse should do for you. It was working until i did the upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADT and SDK Tools must be compatible. 
For example, 
If the latest ADT version is "ADT 23.0.4". And the corresponding SDK Tools version is 23.0.5. You updated your SDK Tools version to 24.0.1, but there are no ADT version can support. So you should roolback to the SDK Tool version 23.0.5. 
Here is the [link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r23.0.5-windows.zip).

It may help you.

Comment: When accessing the link it downloads a file...is it supposed to do that?

Comment: Yes, then you replace tools folder and reopen eclipse

Comment: @Sauron, yes it should download.

Comment: The problem that arises is that the creation of a tabbed layout uses the deprecated methods for action bar. When will the adt be released to allow for the new way to create a tabbed layout?

Comment: @Sauron, for that I would suggest you to use Android Studio instead of Eclipse because Android Studio is official development IDE from now onwards and may be Google will stop support for Eclipse. I think in Android Studio you will not face such problem.

Comment: @VicJordan are there any major differences between eclipse and android studio?