# Eclipse not generating style.xml after update to lollipop sdk

Tags: android, eclipse

I've encounter this problem after I download the latest sdk Android 5.0.1 from Eclipse Android SDK Manager.

First eclipse don't generate the MainActivity.class and MainActivity.xml, but I got that solved but now the style.xml in the values folder are not generated anymore.

I've search through Google for days and wanted to see anyone can help me see whether I've missed steps during updating or what.

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
>   Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
>
> NOTE: This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.
>
> Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I have already answered here. Please try this if it can help  you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27466549/631803

Just for your information. I have added screenshot of my setup.

Comment: should I compare the version with the Android SDK Tools or Android SDK Build Tools?